# JavaScript split method not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a strange problem trying to split a string, I split it once and save it as a variable, but then I try to split the value that I've just created and I can't, it throws an error saying: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

```
justName    = fullLine.split('(', 1)[0];

dateOne     = fullLine.split('(', 2)[1];

dateTwo = dateOne.split(')', 1);

console.log(dateTwo);
```

If I log out justName then there is no problem.

An example of fullLine would be :

```
In the Heat of the Night (1967)
```

Comment: What's the value of "fullLine" here?

Comment: what does fullLine contain?

Comment: The error is saying that the dateOne is undefined. check the value of dateOne in console//

Comment: can you fiddle your code for us?

Comment: 'In the Heat of the Night (1967)'

Comment: Did you find out why this was not working?

Answer (score 1):

I can see it working. Check this jsFiddle here.

```
<div id="a"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="abc()" value="Split" />

function abc(){    
    var fullLine="hello(world)Qwerty";
    justName    = fullLine.split('(', 1)[0];
    dateOne     = fullLine.split('(', 2)[1];
    dateTwo = dateOne.split(')', 1);
    alert(dateTwo);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hA423/13/

Answer (score 1):

```
var str="In the Heat of the Night (1967)"; 
dateOne = str.split('(', 2)[1];
dateTwo = dateOne.split(')', 1);

console.log(dateTwo);
```

It is working fine

Comment: you can check it in your console